# How do you find the general solution of the recurrence relation: $a_n=(a_{n-1})^2+(a_{n-2})^2,a_1=1, a_2=2$

Tags: recurrence-relations

How do I find the general solution of this recurrence relation?
$$a_n=(a_{n-1})^2+(a_{n-2})^2,a_1=1, a_2=2$$
I didn't find any general solution for this recurrence relation.

Comment: If you want to "cheat", [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000283) is one of the first places to look. I searched `1,2,5,29`, and that was the first hit.

Comment: Since https://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticMap.html don't have general solutions, there is probably no general technique for solving this type of problem.  Yours is just a special case with a special solution you could prove with induction or whatever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** The following is rather a hint than an answer. Given is
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{a_n}&\color{blue}{=a_{n-1}^2+a_{n-2}^2\qquad\qquad n\geq 3}\tag{1}\\
\color{blue}{a_1}&\color{blue}{=1, a_2=2}
\end{align*}

The recurrence relation (1) belongs to a group of *doubly exponential sequences* which are analysed in the 1973 paper *[Some doubly exponential sequences](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/244502858_Some_doubly_exponential_sequences)* by A. V. Aho and N. J. A. Sloane.

Some of the sequences analysed in the paper are
\begin{align*}
x_{n+1}&=x_n^2+1 &n\geq 0;\qquad x_0=1\qquad\quad\ \\
y_{n+1}&=y_n^2-y_n+1&n\geq 1;\qquad  y_1=2\qquad\quad\ \\
y_{n+1}&=y_n^2-y_{n-1}^2& n\geq 1;\qquad  y_0=1, y_1=2
\end{align*}

It is shown, that recurrence relations of the form
\begin{align*}
x_{n+1}&=x_n^2+\color{blue}{g_n}\qquad n\geq 0\tag{2}
\end{align*}
with boundary conditions, and such that  the following three conditions
\begin{align*}
x_n&>0\tag{i}\\
\left|g_n\right|&<\frac{1}{4}x_n\qquad\quad n\geq n_0\tag{ii}\\
\left|\alpha_n\right|&\geq \left|\alpha_{n+1}\right|\qquad n\geq n_0\tag{iii}
\end{align*}
are satisfied all have a specific type of solution. For the definition of $\alpha_n$, see below.

Here we write (2) as
\begin{align*}
x_{n+1}&=x_n^2+g_n\\
&=x_n^2\left(1+\frac{g_n}{x_n^2}\right)
\end{align*}
take logarithms and obtain after setting
\begin{align*}
y_n=\ln \left(x_n\right),\qquad \alpha_n=\ln\left(1+\frac{g_n}{x_n^2}\right)
\end{align*}
the recurrence relation
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{y_{n+1}=2y_n+\alpha_n\quad n\geq 0}\tag{3}
\end{align*}

Solving (3) leads to a solution of (2) which is of the form
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{x_n=\left\lfloor K^{2^n}\right\rfloor\qquad n\geq 0}\tag{4}
\end{align*}
with $\color{blue}{K}$ a constant *which needs to be determined*.

> The recurrence relation (1) is also of the form (4) with constant $K$ stated in OEIS *[A000283](https://oeis.org/A000283)* as
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{a_n}&\color{blue}{=\left\lfloor K^{2^n}\right\rfloor\qquad n\geq 1}\\
> \\
> \color{blue}{K}&\color{blue}{=1.235\,392\,737\,785\,436\,889\ldots}
> \end{align*}

**Note:** The first time I read about this type of recurrence relation was many years ago in section 2.2.3 *Doubly Exponential Sequences* in *[Mathematics for the Analysis of Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0817647287)*
by D. E. Knuth and D. H. Greene. There I found the reference to the 1973 paper.

Comment: @Amin: Many thanks for accepting my answer and granting the bounty. :-)